# Limiting addEventListener to componentDidMount using useEffect hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-functional-component, react-class-based-component

I have a class-based component which uses multitouch to add child nodes to an svg and this works well. Now, I am trying to update it to use a functional component with hooks, if for no other reason than to better understand them.

In order to stop the browser using the touch events for gestures, I need to `preventDefault` on them which requires them to *not* be [passive](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Improving_scrolling_performance_with_passive_listeners) and, because of the lack of exposure of the passive configuration within synthetic react events I've needed to use `svgRef.current.addEventListener('touchstart', handler, {passive: false})`. I do this in the `componentDidMount()` lifecycle hook and clear it in the `componentWillUnmount()` hook within the class.

When I translate this to a functional component with hooks, I end up with the following:

```
export default function Board(props) {

    const [touchPoints, setTouchPoints] = useState([]);
    const svg = useRef();

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('add touch start');
        svg.current.addEventListener('touchstart', handleTouchStart, { passive: false });

        return () => {
            console.log('remove touch start');
            svg.current.removeEventListener('touchstart', handleTouchStart, { passive: false });
        }
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('add touch move');
        svg.current.addEventListener('touchmove', handleTouchMove, { passive: false });

        return () => {
            console.log('remove touch move');
            svg.current.removeEventListener('touchmove', handleTouchMove, { passive: false });
        }
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('add touch end');
        svg.current.addEventListener('touchcancel', handleTouchEnd, { passive: false });
        svg.current.addEventListener('touchend', handleTouchEnd, { passive: false });

        return () => {
            console.log('remove touch end');
            svg.current.removeEventListener('touchend', handleTouchEnd, { passive: false });
            svg.current.removeEventListener('touchcancel', handleTouchEnd, { passive: false });
        }
    });


    const handleTouchStart = useCallback((e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        // copy the state, mutate it, re-apply it
        const tp = touchPoints.slice();

        // note e.changedTouches is a TouchList not an array
        // so we can't map over it
        for (var i = 0; i < e.changedTouches.length; i++) {
            const touch = e.changedTouches[i];
            tp.push(touch);
        }
        setTouchPoints(tp);
    }, [touchPoints, setTouchPoints]);

    const handleTouchMove = useCallback((e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        const tp = touchPoints.slice();

        for (var i = 0; i < e.changedTouches.length; i++) {
            const touch = e.changedTouches[i];
            // call helper function to get the Id of the touch
            const index = getTouchIndexById(tp, touch);
            if (index < 0) continue;
            tp[index] = touch;
        }

        setTouchPoints(tp);
    }, [touchPoints, setTouchPoints]);

    const handleTouchEnd = useCallback((e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        const tp = touchPoints.slice();

        for (var i = 0; i < e.changedTouches.length; i++) {
            const touch = e.changedTouches[i];
            const index = getTouchIndexById(tp, touch);
            tp.splice(index, 1);

        }

        setTouchPoints(tp);
    }, [touchPoints, setTouchPoints]);

    return (
        <svg 
            xmlns={ vars.SVG_NS }
            width={ window.innerWidth }
            height={ window.innerHeight }
        >
            { 
                touchPoints.map(touchpoint =>
                    <TouchCircle 
                        ref={ svg }
                        key={ touchpoint.identifier }
                        cx={ touchpoint.pageX }
                        cy={ touchpoint.pageY }
                        colour={ generateColour() }
                    />
                )
            }
        </svg>
    );
}
```

The issue this raises is that every time there is a render update, the event listeners all get removed and re-added. This causes the handleTouchEnd to be removed before it has a chance to clear up added touches among other oddities. I'm also finding that the touch events aren't working unless i use a gesture to get out of the browser which triggers an update, removing the existing listeners and adding a fresh set.

I've attempted to use the dependency list in useEffect and I have seen several people referencing useCallback and useRef but I haven't been able to make this work any better (ie, the logs for removing and then re-adding the event listeners still all fire on every update).

Is there a way to make the useEffect only fire once on mount and then clean up on unmount or should i abandon hooks for this component and stick with the class based one which is working well?

### Edit

I've also tried moving each event listener into its own `useEffect` and get the following console logs:

```
remove touch start
remove touch move
remove touch end
add touch start
add touch move
add touch end
```

### Edit 2

A couple of people have suggested adding a dependency array which I've tried like this:

```
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('add touch start');
        svg.current.addEventListener('touchstart', handleTouchStart, { passive: false });

        return () => {
            console.log('remove touch start');
            svg.current.removeEventListener('touchstart', handleTouchStart, { passive: false });
        }
    }, [handleTouchStart]);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('add touch move');
        svg.current.addEventListener('touchmove', handleTouchMove, { passive: false });

        return () => {
            console.log('remove touch move');
            svg.current.removeEventListener('touchmove', handleTouchMove, { passive: false });
        }
    }, [handleTouchMove]);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('add touch end');
        svg.current.addEventListener('touchcancel', handleTouchEnd, { passive: false });
        svg.current.addEventListener('touchend', handleTouchEnd, { passive: false });

        return () => {
            console.log('remove touch end');
            svg.current.removeEventListener('touchend', handleTouchEnd, { passive: false });
            svg.current.removeEventListener('touchcancel', handleTouchEnd, { passive: false });
        }
    }, [handleTouchEnd]);
```

but I'm still receiving a log to say that each of the `useEffect`s have been removed and then re-added on each update (so every `touchstart`, `touchmove` or `touchend` which causes a paint - which is a lot :) )

### Edit 3

I've replaced `window.(add/remove)EventListener` with `useRef()`

ta

Comment: You can make useEffect() fire only once by passing an empty array as second argument. If its not a one-off action you continue optimize by adding more and more value to the array to fine-tune when React should fire it.

Comment: added an update - tried adding a dependency array including the handlers but i'm still getting constant updates

Comment: useEffect() can return a function to call once at the end (sort of ComponentWillUnmount) I guess its the right place you use your removeListeners

Comment: Thanks for the response - I'm already using the return function for each of the useEffect hooks and this gets called on every paint / update before the listeners are added again (see log in edit 2)

Comment: your code fired more than once even with an empty dependency array?

Comment: actually now you mention it, no - which is great. However now I get another side effect where the handlers cannot change the touchPoints array - there is no error, but the touchPoints array doesn't get updated when setTouchPoints(tp) is called in the handler. In order to affect the state, I need to include both the `touchPoints` array and the `setTouchPoints` function as dependencies

Comment: I've added an answer - not sure how to credit you properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks a lot guys - we got to the bottom of it (w00t)

In order to stop the component `useEffect` hook firing multiple times, it is required to supply an empty dependency array to the hook (as suggested by [Son Nguyen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12983408/son-nguyen) and [wentjun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10959940/wentjun)) however this meant that the current `touchPoints` state was not accessible within the handlers.

The answer (suggested by wentjun) was in [How to fix missing dependency warning when using useEffect React Hook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55840294/how-to-fix-missing-dependency-warning-when-using-useeffect-react-hook)

which mentions the hooks faq: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#what-can-i-do-if-my-effect-dependencies-change-too-often

this is how my component ended up

```
export default function Board(props) {
    const [touchPoints, setTouchPoints] = useState([]);
    const svg = useRef();

    useEffect(() => {
        // required for the return value
        const svgRef = svg.current;

        const handleTouchStart = (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();

            // use functional version of mutator
            setTouchPoints(tp => {
                // duplicate array
                tp = tp.slice();

                // note e.changedTouches is a TouchList not an array
                // so we can't map over it
                for (var i = 0; i < e.changedTouches.length; i++) {
                    const touch = e.changedTouches[i];
                    const angle = getAngleFromCenter(touch.pageX, touch.pageY);

                    tp.push({ touch, angle });
                }

                return tp;
            });
        };

        const handleTouchMove = (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();

            setTouchPoints(tp => {
                tp = tp.slice();

                // move existing TouchCircle with same key
                for (var i = 0; i < e.changedTouches.length; i++) {
                    const touch = e.changedTouches[i];
                    const index = getTouchIndexById(tp, touch);
                    if (index < 0) continue;
                    tp[index].touch = touch;
                    tp[index].angle = getAngleFromCenter(touch.pageX, touch.pageY);
                }

                return tp;
            });
        };

        const handleTouchEnd = (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();

            setTouchPoints(tp => {
                tp = tp.slice();

                // delete existing TouchCircle with same key
                for (var i = 0; i < e.changedTouches.length; i++) {
                    const touch = e.changedTouches[i];
                    const index = getTouchIndexById(tp, touch);
                    if (index < 0) continue;
                    tp.splice(index, 1);
                }

                return tp;
            });
        };

        console.log('add touch listeners'); // only fires once
        svgRef.addEventListener('touchstart', handleTouchStart, { passive: false });
        svgRef.addEventListener('touchmove', handleTouchMove, { passive: false });
        svgRef.addEventListener('touchcancel', handleTouchEnd, { passive: false });
        svgRef.addEventListener('touchend', handleTouchEnd, { passive: false });

        return () => {
            console.log('remove touch listeners');
            svgRef.removeEventListener('touchstart', handleTouchStart, { passive: false });
            svgRef.removeEventListener('touchmove', handleTouchMove, { passive: false });
            svgRef.removeEventListener('touchend', handleTouchEnd, { passive: false });
            svgRef.removeEventListener('touchcancel', handleTouchEnd, { passive: false });
        }
    }, [setTouchPoints]);

    return (
        <svg 
            ref={ svg }
            xmlns={ vars.SVG_NS }
            width={ window.innerWidth }
            height={ window.innerHeight }
        >
            { 
                touchPoints.map(touchpoint =>
                    <TouchCircle 
                        key={ touchpoint.touch.identifier }
                        cx={ touchpoint.touch.pageX }
                        cy={ touchpoint.touch.pageY }
                        colour={ generateColour() }
                    />
                )
            }
        </svg>
    );
}
```

Note: I added `setTouchPoints` to the dependency list to be more declarative

Mondo respect guys

`;oB`

Answer (score 4):

If you only want this to happen when the component is mounted and unmounted, you will need to supply the useEffect hook with an [empty array as the dependency array](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects).

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log('adding event listeners');
    window.addEventListener('touchstart', handleTouchStart, { passive: false });
    window.addEventListener('touchend', handleTouchEnd, { passive: false });
    window.addEventListener('touchcancel', handleTouchEnd, { passive: false });
    window.addEventListener('touchmove', handleTouchMove, { passive: false });

    return () => {
        console.log('removing event listeners');
        window.removeEventListener('touchstart', handleTouchStart, { passive: false });
        window.removeEventListener('touchend', handleTouchEnd, { passive: false });
        window.removeEventListener('touchcancel', handleTouchEnd, { passive: false });
        window.removeEventListener('touchmove', handleTouchMove, { passive: false });
    }
}, []);
```

Comment: if I try this i get the following:   "Line 67:8:  React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'handleTouchStart'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps" for each useEffect (they've been split into separate useEffect calls now)

Comment: added an update - tried the dependency array but i'm still getting near constant updates

Comment: You can consider disabling that particular eslint rule, or you can follow the solutions in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55840294/how-to-fix-missing-dependency-warning-when-using-useeffect-react-hook

Comment: Also, you might want to remove `touchPoints` from `[touchPoints, setTouchPoints]`

Comment: touchPoints is a dependency as its copied, updated and then re-set with setTouchPoints

Comment: I have tried disabling the eslint rule but I end up with some really interesting side effects - the `setTouchPoints` function is called but doesn't actually update the touchPoints state hook seeming to indicate that it doesn't have a reference to the original state hook

Comment: I've added an answer which i would never have got to without your input - thanks so much

Comment: @obie ahh!! Nice!